# Alter primary key column that is also a foreign key of another table - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below 2 tables. They both have data in them. I would like to modify charge_date from a date into a datetime. Mysql is not allowing me to do this. **I would like to do this without dropping and recreating the existing table.**

```
CREATE TABLE `cmpny_charges` (
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `charge_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `charge_date` date NOT NULL,
  `charge_amt` double NOT NULL,
  `chargeholder_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `filing_no` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `srn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charge_type` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `doc_no` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`,`charge_id`,`charge_date`),
  KEY `cmpny_charges_FK_2` (`chargeholder_id`),
  KEY `cmpny_charges_FK_1` (`filing_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `cmpny_charges_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`chargeholder_id`) REFERENCES `chargeholder_dtls` (`chargeholder_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cmpny_charges_FK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `cmpny_charge_dtls` (
  `company_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `charge_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `charge_date` date NOT NULL,
  `modification_part` text,
  `part_property_charged` text,
  `filing_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `srn` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate_of_interest` text,
  `repayment_terms` text,
  `margin` text,
  `nature_instrument` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`,`charge_id`,`charge_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cmpny_charge_dtls_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`, `charge_id`, `charge_date`) REFERENCES `cmpny_charges` (`company_id`, `charge_id`, `charge_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the alter script I would like to execute

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
lock tables cmpny_charges write, cmpny_charge_dtls write;
ALTER TABLE `cmpny_charge_dtls` CHANGE `charge_date` `charge_date` datetime not null;
ALTER TABLE `cmpny_charges` CHANGE `charge_date` `charge_date` datetime not null;
unlock tables ;
set foreign_key_checks =1;
```

I get an error as below when I execute show engine innodb status

LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR

> 140313 19:54:03 Error in foreign key constraint of table
>   csmart/cmpny_charge_dtls: there is no index in referenced table which
>   would contain the columns as the first columns, or the data types in
>   the referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint: ,
>   CONSTRAINT "FK_cmpny_charge_dtls_1" FOREIGN KEY ("company_id",
>   "charge_id", "charge_date") REFERENCES "cmpny_charges" ("company_id",
>   "charge_id", "charge_date") The index in the foreign key in table is
>   "PRIMARY" See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition. InnoDB: Renaming table
>   `csmart`. to
>   `csmart`.`cmpny_charges` failed!

These are the caveats

1. I don't know the name of the constraints for me to drop them temporarily. The same constraints can be present with different names. (I need to update more than one copy of this database)
2. I would like to do this without creating a temp table, copying the data there and then renaming them to the original one. This caused issues when multiple sessions logged into the same database tried to do the same thing at the same time leaving it in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Not exactly sure how it works in MySQL but in SQL server if column is part of primary key you can not modify it. You would first have to drop primary constrain, then alter column, then create primary key again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column, copy data into it. Then modify the foreign key to point to the new column, and the drop the old column.

```
alter table cmpny_charges add charge_date2 datetime;
update cmpny_charges set charge_date2= charge_date;

-- (I am used to do this via GUI, sorry...)
-- drop foreing key
---modify the primary key 
-- recreate the foreing key

alter table cmpny_charges drop charge_date;
```